# How do i reduce padding space between UICollectionView cells in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, uicollectionview

[I want to have 3 cells in one row and I am only able to place 2 cells in the collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKte2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` and `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to smaller value:

```swift
var reducedPadding: CGFloat = 8

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return reducedPadding
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return reducedPadding
}
```

Comment: for anyone googling here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60138260/294884